# c++ template within class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a function within a class that is passed a function and its parameters, it then binds them into a function call and calls the function among others things.

This has been hacked together quickly to test a concept i know the code isn't great.

```
class Profiling {
public: 
    template<class _Fn, class... _Args> GetProfile(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax);
    int GetTime();
    char Type;
    int Size;
private:
    int StartTime;
    int EndTime;
};
template<class _Fn, class... _Args> Profiling::GetProfile(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
{
    StartTime = clock();
    function<void()> f = _STD bind(_Decay_copy(_STD forward<_Fn>(_Fx)), _Decay_copy(_STD forward<_Args>(_Ax))...);
    f();
    EndTime = clock();

}
int Profiling::GetTime() {
    return EndTime - StartTime;
}
```

I get this error

> Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: What should be the return type of `GetProfile`?

Comment: What is `_STD`?   Note that a name with a leading underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved to the implementation for any purpose.  As such, using it in your own code is undefined behaviour.  (And if it's a #define for `std::`, I have to ask ***why?*** - it doesn't even save any typing.)

Comment: @MartinBonner In Microsoft's C++ standard library, `_STD` is defined as `::std::` in the internal `yvals.h` header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a return type for your function.

```
template<class _Fn, class... _Args>
/* return type here */ GetProfile(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax);
```

Since you don't return anything in the function, `void` would be the appropriate return type.

Comment: Thanks,I did try this after i posted after in realised but now get "Error 2 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Comment: Sorry, this was caused by something else. Thanks for your help!